# docker on Azure VM windows 10

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-machine

i am trying to install the docker on the windows 10 machine in Azure which has the VS community edition. Is it possible to install the docker on windows 10 VM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no,

as Azure is not supporting nested virtualisation.
If you want to test docker and containers in Azure, try an Azure Server 2016 or Windows 10 Pro at home

Comment: Now, it is possible.  DV3 and EV3 support nested virtualisation. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/nested-virtualization-in-azure/

Answer (score 0):

You have to use *Standard* Security Type when using the D4ds_v4 or similar and then expose virtualization extensions after installing the Hyper-V PowerShell Feature.

```
Add-WindowsFeature @("Hyper-V-PowerShell")
Install-Module -Name DockerMsftProvider -Repository PSGallery
Get-VM WinContainerHost | Set-VMProcessor -ExposeVirtualizationExtensions $true
wsl --install
```